# Event logs on multiple server

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-event-log, query

I am looking for tools that will allow me to aggregate and query event logs from multiple servers.

In my case, this is a webfarm and I need to be able to query the event logs for all of them in one place.

Can anyone recommend such a tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few products I am aware of that will do this:

- [System Center Ops Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/operationsmanager/en/us/default.aspx)
- [LogMeister (and EventMeister)](http://www.tlhouse.co.uk/LogMeister/)
- [DAD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lassie/) - Opensource

Personally I only have experience with System Center (although I;m looking to setup DAD). System centre has some very nice functionality, but it can feel a bit bloated at times as well.

Comment: +1 for EventMeister, but I beat you to the punch by 6 seconds. ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of products that can do this. EventMeister is one, at a pretty reasonable price.

http://www.tlhouse.co.uk/LogMeister/shop.shtml

Comment: +1 For getting there first :)